# Entity in not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

I'm getting exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Building is not mapped [from Building]`
My Building class mapped

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "building")
public class Building extends AbstractModel {
```

AbstractModel is empty (just for upcast)

Setting packagesToScan

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
       ....
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.app.persistence.model");
      ....
    }
```

Code throws excetion

```
public <M extends AbstractModel> List<M> findAll() {
    List<Building> buildings;

    try {
        buildings = (List<Building>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Building");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return (List<M>) buildings;
}
```

Also i setuped

```
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean(DataSource ds) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with `Building` class itself or with `AbstractModel`. Hard to say, a lot of details are omitted

Comment: Why are you configuring a JPA EntityManagerFactory but start using plain Hibernate?! You also need to setup the `SessionFactory` accordingly (although I would suggest to simply use JPA instead of plain hibernate).

Comment: are you using javax.persistence.Table or org.hibernate.annotations.Table?

Comment: javax.persistence. annotations, also other entities in project have same problem

Comment: i have to use hibernate 5 in this project

Comment: If you need Hibernate 5, configure a Hibernate `SessionFactory` bean instead of JPA `EntityManagerFactory`. Also please give the lines above `buildings = (List<Building>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Building");`

Comment: i setuped LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: The fact that you use hibernate doesn't mean you cannot use JPA... Hibernate is a JPA provider... So the argument that you have to use Hibernate5 doesn't really hold (as you can perfectly use that and still use it with JPA).

Comment: Don't add additional code as comments edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring an `EntityManagerFactory` which is for use with JPA however in your code you are using the plain Hibernate API, which requires a correctly configured `SessionFactory` instead.

Instead of using plain hibernate I strongly suggest to simply use JPA instead. Just rewrite your code to use an `EntityManager` instead of `Session` and/or `HibernateTemplate` (The latter is something you should avoid using as that isn't recommended anymore since hibernate 3.0.1!).

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public <M extends AbstractModel> List<M> findAll() {
    return em.createQuery("select b FROM Building b", Building.class).getResultList();
}
```

And remove the setup of plain hibernate i.e. the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` configuration and `HibernateTemplate` setup.

This is all you need. Now if you would add Spring Data JPA into the mix you don't even need this, you would only need a `BuildingRepository` interface.

```
public interface BuildingRepository extends JpaRepository<Building, Long> {}
```

Assuming that the id is of type `Long`.

If you really want to use plain Hibernate (which as stated is something I wouldn't recommend) you need to configure your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` correctly and specify the `packagesToScan` for it as well.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean(DataSource ds) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.app.persistence.model");
    return localSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately hibernate 5 is a part of technical specifications of this project, so i can't avoid it

Comment: As stated before the fact that you use hibernate, doesn't mean that you cannot use JPA... Hibernate == JPA Provider.. So you can adhere to that technical spec perfectly while using JPA.

Comment: thanks for advice, i will operate your answers if anything and use Spring Data